# Spring Boot PropertyLauncher/JarLauncher with external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

We are building multi layer Dockerfile where jar will be decomposed into multiple layers. For decomposing jar, we are using command `-Djarmode=layertools`

We need to launch app with external jar, so giving external jar path via `-Dloader.main`

We are launching app via JarLauncher
But, property file which is yaml is not available when app is launched. Exception is FileNotFoundException for property.yaml file.

How can we fix this issue ?

Tried PropertiesLauncher but classes are not available at runtime.

Comment: Please post code snippets to analyze if possible